# Javascript: Multiple Switch Statements in a loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, switch-statement, break

I have a while loop and my requirement is to pass data to a variable based on first three characters of a string and another data into another variable based on last three characters of a string. So, I used two switch statements in a while loop and it looks like below

```
while (condition) {
  switch (firstThreeChars) {
    case 'a':
          do this;
          break;
    case 'b':
          do this...;
          break;
  }
  switch (lastThreeChars) {
    case 'x':
          do this;
          break;
    case 'y':
          do this...;
          break;
  }  
}
```

I realized that code never reaches second switch because break in first switch-case releases control to while statement. Is there a way I can have multiple switch-case statements in a while loop? Perhaps something alternative to break statement..

Comment: of course you can maybe your case#2 is not reaching x and y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's incorrect; the `break` keywords terminate the `switch` statements, not the `while`. The problem here is that you're comparing your strings to single characters, so you're likely never matching any of the `case` statements.